# How to retrieve the dimensions of a numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am very new to learning python and I am trying to scale a matrix using library `np. array` **n x m**.
the question : if a matrix with using library `np.array` is given as input and I don't know how big the range the matrix, how can I initialize the size of **m**? Are there certain **features or tricks** in Python that can be used for this?

```
import numpy as np
def scaleArray(arr: np.array);
arrayB = np.array([[1,2,4],
                   [3,4,5],
                   [2,1,0],
                   [0,1,0]])
scaleArray(b)
```

This `arrayB` is just for example.

**Expected output :**

```
3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scale"? can you give some desired input and output?

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 5):

`arr.shape` is what you are looking for, it gives you the dimensions of the nD array.

In your case, you want `arr.shape[1]`

Comment: As I've said in the answer, `m` is given by `arr.shape[1]`.

Comment: I don't know how to say it other than that. `m=arr.shape[1]`.

Comment: @jeryozdimitar The answer of Matthieu is correct and complete. You can get `m` and `n` with it. You should mark it as accepted.